# Android custom toolbar navigation up

Tags: android, navigation, android-toolbar

I have an app with two activities and two different toolbars. I want to navigate back to the main activity from the second one. I added the parent activity in the manifest.xml and the listener in the second activity but nothing, the back arrow is there but it doesn't work.

Here the code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_fw_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_fw_light"
    android:name=".RxApplication">

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".WebPageActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
</application>
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_search"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Calling onCreate for HomeActivity");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutRedIs());

    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

and the second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Calling onCreate for SearchActivity");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutRedIs());

    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
    tb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
    tb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: you need to implement the onclick listener in the toolbar navigation icon

Comment: I was able to solve it by myself using a CoordinatorLayout and controlling the style in the manifest for each activity. I didn't need to add any onclick listener since it is managed by android itself using the parentActivityName